# Installing PIConnect on Python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems I was able to install successfully the `PIConnect` module with `pip install PIConnect`. However I'm not being able to import the module as you can see bellow.

```
D:\Python310\Scripts>pip install PIConnect
Collecting PIConnect
  Using cached PIconnect-0.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in d:\python310\lib\site-packages (from PIConnect) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pythonnet in d:\python310\lib\site-packages\pythonnet-3.0.0a2-py3.10.egg (from PIConnect) (3.0.0a2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in d:\python310\lib\site-packages (from PIConnect) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: future in d:\python310\lib\site-packages (from PIConnect) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt in d:\python310\lib\site-packages (from PIConnect) (1.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in d:\python310\lib\site-packages (from pandas->PIConnect) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in d:\python310\lib\site-packages (from pandas->PIConnect) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: clr-loader in d:\python310\lib\site-packages\clr_loader-0.1.7-py3.10.egg (from pythonnet->PIConnect) (0.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in d:\python310\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas->PIConnect) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.13 in d:\python310\lib\site-packages (from clr-loader->pythonnet->PIConnect) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in d:\python310\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.13->clr-loader->pythonnet->PIConnect) (2.21)
Installing collected packages: PIConnect
Successfully installed PIConnect-0.9.1

D:\Python310\Scripts>cd ..

D:\Python310>python
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PIConnect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIConnect'
>>>
```

### Question

How can I solve this problem importing the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `PIconnect`, not `PIConnect` ([Documentation](https://piconnect.readthedocs.io/en/develop/tutorials/piserver.html)).